# How to dynamically draw a recangle on the screen without glitching - python

Tags: python, wxpython, screen, drawrectangle, visual-glitch

https://media.giphy.com/media/3og0IDneIpXgdMDOzm/source.gif

I am working on a code that draws a transparent rectangle on screen and saves the section as an image, yet excessive rectangles are being left behind.

```
import wx
import win32gui

app = wx.App(False)
s = wx.ScreenDC()
s.Pen = wx.Pen("#FF0000")

int_x = win32gui.GetCursorPos()[0]
int_y = win32gui.GetCursorPos()[1]

while 1:
    s.DrawRectangle(int_x,int_y,win32gui.GetCursorPos()[0]-int_x,win32gui.GetCursorPos()[1]-int_y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to do some kind of clear or refresh after the draw

```
s.Clear()
s.Refresh()
```

I haven't used this so I'm not sure if it will just work in your while loop but I'd imagine it won't and you would need something to handle the start (mousedown) and end (mouseup) of the drawing and then on mouseup do the clear and refresh that i mention.

Comment: error pops up: AttributeError: 'ScreenDC' object has no attribute 'Refresh'